# Show another window after five seconds

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I want to make a WPF pogram like this:
When run the program,the main window shows,five seconds later,another window shows.
How can I achieve it? I have seen the timer,but I can't do it.

Comment: whta you can not do with Timer ? What is your problem with it ?

Comment: Before I think use timer can achieve the function,but I don't know how to do.

Comment: Are you talking about a [splash screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656886.aspx)?

Comment: No,just jump to another window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Kshitij Mehta for pointer regarding DispatcherTimer.

In your `MainWindow`, define a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) and pop up another window on [Tick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.tick.aspx) like this -

```
    DispatcherTimer timer = null;
    void StartTimer()
    {
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();

        AnotherWindow window = new AnotherWindow();
        window.Show();
    }
```

Call `StartTimer()` in your `MainWindow` constructor.

```
    public MainWindow
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StartTimer();
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying it,but it seems has some questions now.The another window can't show.

Comment: Can you post the code for whatever you have tried..??

Comment: Just copy the code above,the WPF application only has two windows:MainWindow and AnotherWindow.

Comment: then what is the error??

Comment: Only show the MainWindow and never change.

Comment: please provide code for your MainWindow for further help...

Comment: OK,I get it.I have used some code you gave me first time.It's my fault.Thank you so much.

Comment: No Probs... Happy to help..;)

Answer (score 4):

You want to use a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28VS.95%29.aspx) for this. Prateek Singh has almost got it right. I'd just change his Timer to a DispatcherTimer so it runs on the UI thread.

Comment: +1 for DispatcherTimer... More suitable in this scenario...!!

Comment: I'm not understand it.In fact,I only start wpf for two week by myself.